# JPA criteria delete continuously fall with strange exception, in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a jpa entity witch is some kind of http request log, and i wanted to create a scheduled task where delet old entries also, deled older on application start up.

I can delete one at one, but when i want to bulk delet older ones i always get the same exception (see below)

I created a custom repository with one method `void cleanLog();`

```
    public class RequestLogRepositoryImpl implements RequestLogRepositoryCustom {

    private final LogWrapper log = new LogWrapper(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "someQualifier")
    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf;

    @Autowired
    private CleanUpProperties cleanUpProperties;

    private EntityManager em;
    private CriteriaBuilder cb;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postBusinessEventRepositoryCustomImpl() {
        this.em = emf.getNativeEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        this.cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanLog() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(cleanUpProperties.getField().getValue(), -(cleanUpProperties.getLength()));

        log.info("Delete before :" + calendar.getTime());

        CriteriaDelete<RequestLogEntity> delete = cb.createCriteriaDelete(RequestLogEntity.class);
        Root<RequestLogEntity> root = delete.from(RequestLogEntity.class);

        delete.where(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("requestTime"), calendar.getTime()));

        em.createQuery(delete).executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

It's create the delete query correctly, but when try to execute it alwasy fals with the same exception, no matter it's on start up, or scheduled task or directly want to run it though the app admin interface.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing
>   an update/delete query; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]

In the service where i call this repository method is annotated with `@Transactional` witch mean this should been in transaction. According my resource i also should use `@Modifying` annotation along with `@Transactional` but also didn't work with it.

This is how my service method looks like, this is where i catch the exception

```
@Override
@Modifying
@Transactional
public boolean clearLog() {
    try{
        requestLogRepository.cleanLog();
    }catch (Exception e){
        log.fatal("Error:", e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating your own EntityManager instance, unaware of the Spring transaction handling.

Just inject the entity manager:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: @PersistenceContext(unitName="someQualifier") for this occasion, the app use more data source, and getting the factory was bad practice that i learn from legacy code. Funny thing it's works correctly in many other place.